# message not delivered to email -ruby on rails-

Tags: ruby

i tried to send message to mail by using ruby on rails but it not delivered 
Although 0 error in the code

```
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to My site")
```

con

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "username",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
     RegistedMailer.sendingmail(@profolio).deliver
```

note
the application buit on localhost

Answer (score 0):

What is the setting for delivery method ? It should be:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Comment: new error>>   No such file or directory - /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -f

Answer (score 0):

In development mode, Rails does not send out the email. Make sure you set this, [per the Rails Guides Action Mailer Configuration for GMail](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) page:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

If that's already set, can you post your log?

You may also want to investigate [something like MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me), which makes it easier to test emails in development mode.

Comment: $RAILS_ENV refers to the "Rails environment". There are three out of the box: `development`, `testing` and `production`. So, in the development environment, you would edit the `development.rb` file.